# Node.js connection library for LibreOffice Base database?

Tags: database, node.js, hsqldb, libreoffice

I'd like to use LibreOffice's database application (Base) for a small, single user Node.js app I'm writing.  I believe Base uses an HSQLDB backend.  What Node.js libraries are available to me to execute SQL statements against an .odb database file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such thing exists that connects and executes statements against an .odb database file, other than Base itself.

If you setup LibreOffice to use an external HSQLDB Server, which is pretty simple, then other libraries can connect to this Server as well.

But as far as I know, there is currently no connectivity module for node.js to connect via JDBC, which is supported by HSQLDB.

You may have to use Base to connect to a MySQL server and connect to this server from node.js

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, because I've done my personal portfolio with an mdb file that I need to convert data to use odb file.

Probably it is needed an odbc connection with a Dsn. I suppose that the only way is to use odbc, I think I will try to use this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/odbc

Another tools you can try is:

https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/access-odbc-nodejs.rst

Comment: This reads like a log, could you [edit] to turn this into an answer according to [answer]?

Comment: I've edited and corrected my answer. It is my first one on stackoverflow, I have to learn

Comment: Well done listening to feedback. However, it now seems even more of a log than a solution. Also, please understand that linked content is not considered part of the answer. So please less of "I have the same problem" and of "I need to..." and more about the background why converting to odb might help. Also more assertive phrasing would probably be helpful. Be honest about things you do not know, but if you have to write "probably" then the answer might not be so convincing. Can you describe what you found out, what you know, instead of what you guess?

Comment: As soon as I will have a tryout or solution I will post it. Now I did not not solve the problem yet